# jQuery Radio button

Tags: jquery

I was wondering why this isn't working properly on IE, when you choose a radio button?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[name='crkbrd']").change(function(){
    if ($("input[name='crkbrd']:checked").val() == 'Upload')
       { alert("Upload Your Own Ad"); }
    else if ($("input[name='crkbrd']:checked").val() == 'Edit')
        { alert("Edit Your Ad Here"); }
    else
      { alert("You haven't chosen anything"); }
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" id="rb1" name="crkbrd" value="Upload" /> Upload Your Own Ad<br />
<input type="radio" id="rb2" name="crkbrd" value="Edit" /> Edit Your Ad Here
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE has a bug with radio buttons in that it doesn't fire the change event until the radio button is blurred.  Use the click event instead.

Bug details: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-193-onchange-does-not-fire-properly.html

*Note this bug was fixed in IE9 (as long as you are running in standards mode)*

Answer (score 0):

I have this working on IE 8, Firefox and chrome browsers

Try assigning a `class` attribute to the radio buttons as:

```
<input type="radio" id="rb1" name="crkbrd" value="Upload" class="myRadio" /> Upload Your Own Ad<br />
<input type="radio" id="rb2" name="crkbrd" value="Edit" class="myRadio" /> Edit Your Ad Here
```

and then use the following:

```
 $( ".myRadio" ).change( function(){ 
    if ($(this).val() == 'Upload') { 
       alert("Upload Your Own Ad"); 
    } else 
     if ($(this).val() == 'Edit') { 
        alert("Edit Your Ad Here"); 
     } else { 
      alert("You haven't chosen anything");
     } 

 });
```

Comment: So how would you know which of the buttons are selected?

Comment: your definition of the `change` function will be same:

`$( ".myRadio" ).change( function(){ 
    if ($(this).val() == 'Upload')
       { alert("Upload Your Own Ad"); }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'Edit')
        { alert("Edit Your Ad Here"); }
    else
      { alert("You haven't chosen anything"); }
});`

Comment: Oh i get what you mean now. Thanks

Comment: btw what virtual platform do you run older versions of ie on?

Comment: I don't check browser compatibility. Luckily the company I work with doesn't care if older browsers don't work with our code. Our target visitors are `FF`, `chrome`, and `IE` 8+